# Preselect multiple items in SelectListBox

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

As the title stated I'd like to preselect items when the view loads. I have this code:

```
@{
    var categoryList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    foreach (var category in ViewBag.Categories)
    {
        categoryList.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = category.CategoryId.ToString(),
            Text = category.Name,
            Selected = category.Assigned
        });
    }
}
@Html.ListBox("Categories", categoryList, new { @class = "select-toggle", size = 5 })
```

This is roughly outputted as:

```
"1", "Category 1", true
"2", "Category 2", false
"3", "Category 3", false
"4", "Category 4", false
"5", "Category 5", true
```

However it does not pre-select the items when I load the page. I have tried several possible solutions like different formats and selecting the categories from the model but they do not seem to work in my case. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally prefer to use a view model to transfer data between a view and an action method (to load data to view and pass the posted form values back to action method). So let's solve this problem by creating a view model.

```
public class CreateProductVm
{
   public int ID { set;get;}
   public string Name { set;get;}
   public List<SelectListItem> Categories { set;get;}
   public int[] SelectedCategories { set;get;}
   //Add other properties as needed by the view
}
```

Now in your GET action method, we will create an object of this view model, load the `Categories` property and send that object to the view. If you want to pre select some items in the listbox, you can load the `SelectedCategories` property.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
  //get the Product from db using id and assign to the properties of our view model
  var vm = new CreateProductVm();
  // Hard coded items for demo. You may replace with data from your db table(s)
  vm.Categories = new List<SelectListItem> {
                                            new SelectListItem { Value="1", Text="Books"},
                                            new SelectListItem { Value="2", Text="Toys"},
                                            new SelectListItem { Value="3", Text="Phone"}, 
                                            new SelectListItem { Value="4", Text="Cars"}
  };
  vm.SelectedCategories = new[] {2, 3}; // To preselect Toys & Phone
  return View(vm);
}
```

Now your view will be strongly typed to our view model

```
@model CreateProductVm
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.Name)
  @Html.HiddenFor(g=>g.Id)
  @Html.ListBoxFor(x=>x.SelectedCategories ,Model.Categories)
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

Now when the form is submitted, you can read the `SelectedCategories` property to get the selected Categories in your HttpPost action assuming your method takes an object of CreateProductVm class as the parameter

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(CreateProductVm model)
{
  //check for model.SelectedCategories;
  var p =db.Products.FirstOrDefault(s=>s.Id==model.Id);
  if(p!=null)
  {
    p.Name = model.Name;
   //Update other properties as needed
   db.SaveChanges();
   return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
  // to do : return something
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I get an error stating I need to return a Product object. I don't need the preselecting on the Create method, but on the Edit method. On create the user selects categories, on edit it must be visible which are selected and which not. And it must be editable ofcourse. I'm new with the ViewModel

Comment: Where are you getting that error ? You are not using a Product object anywhere in my answer. The only place you need to use it is in your HttpPost action where you will read the properties of model and assign it to your entity object( Product)

Comment: I'm working in the ProductController, when I need to edit a Product it needs to select all the current categories in a selectlist. The product has many categories and a category can have many products (many-to-many).

Comment: So what ? The selectedcategories property is an array type and it should work for multiple categories

Comment: Yes, it was just for information. When I try to return the viewmodel in the Edit function in the ProductsController, it gives me an error: Webshop.ViewModels.CreateProductVm is not assignable to model type 'Webshop.Models.Product

Comment: In my answer i have mentioned that your view should be strongly typed to the view model, not the product entity class.

Comment: It works now :D I don't know why it wouldn't accept the vm at first :/. Can you explain why my code didn't work or is it totally wrong? Is there an easy way to bind the properties of the model to the viewmodel? Or do I have to do it like: id = product.id, name = product.name, description = product.description?

Comment: You can consider using a library like Auto mapper to do the mapping from your view model to your entity model. BTW, I do manual mapping :)

Comment: Okay, thanks for all your help. If I understand correctly you would do something like this too? : http://pastebin.com/sh5CSrPU

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with the following. And it seems to work fine.

```
@{
var categoryList = new List<SelectListItem>()
                   {
                       new SelectListItem()
                       {
                            Value = "1",
                            Text = "One",
                            Selected = true
                       },
                        new SelectListItem()
                       {
                            Value = "2",
                            Text = "Two",
                            Selected = false
                       },
                         new SelectListItem()
                       {
                            Value = "3",
                            Text = "Three",
                            Selected = true
                       }
                   };

}
@Html.ListBox("Categories", categoryList, new { @class = "select-toggle", size = 5 })
```

Are you sure about your output ? Maybe try with this example.